# What internal function does dict value and items use, and how do I overwrite them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I'm trying to write a class that inherits from dictionary and overwrote `__setitem__` and `__getitem__` and everything was going so well until I noticed that `items` and `values` do not use `__getitem__`. Anyone know how to overwrite their look up functions?

Example implementation below:

```
class ReturnStringsDict(dict):

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        """Return value only."""
        return str(super().__getitem__(key))


test = ReturnStringsDict()
test['a'] = 1
test['b'] = 2

# Throws assertion error.
for value in test.values():
    assert isinstance(value, str)

# Throws assertion error.
for key, value in test.items():
    assert test[key] == value
```

Comment: why do you need your own container?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov: well an idea is to subclass `dict` to something like a `Counter`,...

Comment: there are already a lot of containers in [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) package and others, why to reinvent the wheel? only as an example, i guess

Comment: @AzatIbrakov: yeah I know there is a `Counter`. What I mean is that you sometimes want a custom "dictionary" type to carry out a special task (like for instance the `collection` package does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation on emulating container types (https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types), you should implement `items()` and `values()` (and a few others) directly.

It might help to implement `__iter__`, because that's what a lot of those functions do, but you should really check the docs here.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried overwriting `__iter__` but `__iter__` on a dict only yields the keys. Thanks for the ref to the docs, should have looked there.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can **overwrite** the `values()` and `items()` functions:

```
class ReturnStringsDict(dict):

    # ...

    def values(self):
        for v in super().values():
            yield str(v)

    def items(self):
        for k,v in super().items():
            yield k,str(v)
```

As far as I know dictionaries are *not* implemented in Python itself. So they do not use Python code to obtain a key or value. Simply overwriting the `__getitem__` will thus not work since `values()` are implemented at the interpreter level. [This is for instance the source code of a Python dictionary of Python 2.6.6](http://svn.python.org/view/*checkout*/python/tags/r266/Objects/dictobject.c?revision=84293&content-type=text/plain).